# Is there any way to link to a chrome webstore user?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

Im making a website, and i want to link to my chrome webstore user, where all my projects are. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be such a public page.

There's "more from this developer" section of an item listing, under "Related" (which you can link to), but it shows only a sampling of your items.

[image: "Related" tab]

Comment: I cant seem to find the option youre talking about. I went to my app, and then to related, but there is just more apps from other developers.

Comment: It should show a random sampling of other public extensions by the same developer in the bottom row. But how Google selects them is not very clear.

Comment: I added a screenshot for clarity